# "Restful" resources in rails: session[:user_id] = user.id syntax when session is a resource but not a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, session, authentication

Working through authentication in RailsCasts, there was [one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised) where I didn't understand something completely fundamental and important (it's pro, sorry - you need to be subscribed to access it).

He creates a user model with an email and encrypted password (has_secure_password).

Then he makes a new controller called Sessions, and declares it as a resource in the config. i.e.

```
resources :sessions
```

Then, inside the sessions controller, he defines the create method like this:

```
user = find user and authenticate
if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
else ...
```

But sessions as a model doesn't exist. For instance, if I open up my console and write

```
sessions[:user_id] = "hello"
```

it throws. Does anyone have an explanation or a link to this very basic concept that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks Sanfor. Typo fixed, also for markup plus most importantly an answer!

Comment: The particularly confusing thing here, on further reflection, is that "session" has nothing to do with my SessionsConroller (code-wise). Session is something maintained by ActionController. My googling was, hence, completely misdirected. Just in case that's a useful comment for anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have copied the *session* as *sessions* in your question, is that correct? The screen cast is revised, so you'd need to be subscribed what I'm not nowadays so can't confirm it more than what comments say.

Now to the actual answer, the session is Rails internal reference to the actual session on hand as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) and for that reason you can't see the model for it created.

Comment: Thanks heaps. That link is exactly what I was asking about that didn't know about.

Comment: Hi @Tony Wright if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic explanation:

`session` is just a hash and stored as a cookie. (Unless you specifically instructed Rails to store it in the database). Models are typically ActiveRecord based and have some behavior.

You can add to it by simply

```
  session[:some_thing] = "Info for session"
  session[:store_this_too] = "Some other info to track for this session"
```

The `session` hash is created by the controller-related class/modules and `rails console` doesn't load them. Therefore, it is not available in the console.

Here's a pretty **old** [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/84-cookie-based-session-store) which explains a bit more. And [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model) which takes the model-based approach. Bear in mind they are from the old days.

Comment: Thanks roob. That is a clear concise explanaion. I didn't know that about the console. Really helpful.